# Can I set the Brick Texture Node horizontal mortar size to be equivalent to the vertical mortar size?

Tags: node-editor

I'm using Blender 2.73 and I'm trying to create tiles using the brick texture node.  The problem I'm having is that the horizontal mortar size is smaller than the vertical.

Is it possible to have them be equivalent sizes?

Comment: Could you better explain what you mean - maybe post some screenshots. From my testing, it seems they're already of the same size, so I'm not sure what you mean.

Comment: I think pressing Ctrl+A and applying scale while the object is selected might help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The main reason of this answer is to combat the erroneous views as to why the brick texture is distorted.

**The mortar attribute is a constant set by the *Mortar Size* option, not a percentage.**

---

This issue is caused by scaling the mesh that the texture is applied to. Applying the scale will not change anything, as the generated UV's for the brick texture still remain the same. You need to UV unwrap your mesh properly and use that to drive the brick texture UV coordinates.

A default plane will give this result:
[image]

While a scaled one will give this result:
[image]

Again, applying scale does nothing. I tried it, several times. Instead, UV unwrap the mesh and set up your nodes like this (or try @chebhou's suggestion):

[image]

Now you can change the UV unwrapping and the mortar will change in width as well. You may need to change the size of your bricks once you have the mortar size correct.

Answer (score 7):

<del>the mortar size is a percentage of the width or height so they won't be equal unless width = height
or</del>  you can try this :
[image]

tweak the scale on the Y axis till you get the effect

Comment: This is not the case. I changed the width to an outrageously large size, and kept the height, and the mortar sizes remained the same. Whats more, the mortar size is consistent.

Comment: Although this method does work at achieving the desired result I had to change the accepted answer to best solution.